# Python: replace() - I cant get it to work correctly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, apply

I have searched and searched and tried so many different things, but I simply cant get it to work.

Here goes:

I am trying to use the replace-function to 'search' through all columns in a Pandas DataFrame and replace #CRNCY# with the value from the column CRNCY

After searching and trying with replace, applymap and other solutions I give up.
It seems like replace() is the way to go - and I have tried all of the below:

```
test = test.replace("#CRNCY#",test['CRNCY'], regex = True)
test = test.replace("#CRNCY#",test['CRNCY'], regex = True, inplace=True)
test = test.replace("#CRNCY#",test['CRNCY'].tolist(), regex = True)
test = test.replace("#CRNCY#",test.CRNCY, regex = True)
```

but nothing seem to work.

If I just run the below all instances of #CRNCY# is replaced with blabla - that is not what I want - but it shows that something works. I just am not smart enough to figure out what? (Note: I have only been using Python for a short while, so still learning by doing and I am not a developer :])

```
test = test.replace("#CRNCY#",'blabla', regex = True)
```

print(test.head(10))
SECURITIES  SCD_CUR CRNCY
0  ARARGE3209S6  #CRNCY#   USD
1  ARARGE3209Y4  #CRNCY#   USD
2  AT0000A04967  #CRNCY#   EUR
3  AT0000A0DXC2  #CRNCY#   EUR
4  AT0000A0U299  #CRNCY#   EUR
5  AT0000A10683  #CRNCY#   EUR
6  AT0000A185T1  #CRNCY#   EUR
7  AT0000A1FAP5  #CRNCY#   EUR
8  CL0002172501  CLP   COU
9  COL17CT02625  #RULE60#   EUR

print(test.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 20842 entries, 0 to 20841
Data columns (total 3 columns):

## Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype

---

0   SECURITIES  20842 non-null  object
1   SCD_CUR     20813 non-null  object
2   CRNCY       20827 non-null  object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 488.6+ KB
None

```
test = test.replace("#CRNCY#",test['CRNCY'], regex = True)
test = test.replace("#CRNCY#",test['CRNCY'], regex = True, inplace=True)
test = test.replace("#CRNCY#",test['CRNCY'].tolist(), regex = True)
test = test.replace("#CRNCY#",test.CRNCY, regex = True)
```